# Execute azure command in powrershell without writing error to console?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using powershell script in pipeline and the problem I have with this query.

```
$value = $(az appconfig kv show -n ThisisEnv --key thisisconfigkey) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

What this query does is get the data related to key if exist. If this key doesn't exist it give the error like

```
ERROR: Key 'abcdefg' with label 'None' does not exist.
```

It is work as expected. In pipeline when the key  doesn't exist, it's printed a error on CLI. The pipeline see it as error and show it as failed. Is there a way I can make it work.

Is there a way I can stop it printing it on console. Any powershell operator which help me to get the value from azure command but also let me get it without print anything on console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to redirect the standard error using `2> $null`

```
$value = $(az appconfig kv show -n ThisisEnv --key thisisconfigkey 2> $null) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

This will suppress the error within the console. You might also want to set the  `powerShellIgnoreLASTEXITCODE` within the [Azure CLI Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) in order that the pipeline run doesn't fail - or as a workaround, set the `$LASTEXITCODE` to `0`

Comment: I tried 2> $null, it still print the error on console.

Comment: My fault, I misplaced the statement. Please try again - I edited my answer.

Comment: This codesnippt help me to stop showing error but my pipeline still seeing same  error. Is there a way I can prevent this. I am no longer able to reproduce it on locally but pipeline still same.